# Can anyone please explain to me the difference of the two variants of making a set from a list?

Tags: python, set

I'm new in python and I got confused. Can anyone please explain to me the difference of the two variants of making a set from a list? Which one is more correct?

```
a = ["Jake", "John", "Eric"]
b = ["John", "Jill"]
c = set([])
d = set([])
for i in range (len(a)):
    c.add(a[i])

for y in range (len(b)):
    d.add(b[y])
print c.difference(d)    
import sets
e= sets.Set(a)
print e
f = sets.Set(b)
print f
print e.difference(f)

Outcome
set(['Jake', 'Eric'])
Set(['Jake', 'Eric'])
```

Thanx!

Comment: You can also make a set from a list by simply calling set on list.  `set([1,2,3])`

Comment: And now for something completely different: Don't use `for i in range (len(a)): c.add(a[i])`. Go the Python way and use `for value in a: c.add(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't take a for loop to convert a list to set:

```
a = ["Jake", "John", "Eric"]
b = ["John", "Jill"]
print set(a) - set(b)
```

use `set` object instead of `sets.Set()`, `sets.Set()` is deprecated.